# Node.js File System passing values from browser

Tags: node.js

I know how I can simply write a file using nodes File System. However, I have a simple HTML page with an input. I want to use javascript to get the value of the input submitted by a user and take this value and add it into the file written by node.

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('mynewfile3.txt', 'This is my text' + <VARIABLE>, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Replaced!');
});
```

Where  is the value being pulled in from the javascript on the input.

Comment: Create a route for a POST request, add the variable to the body of the POST request and call this function when the route is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Express, the `req` object has a property called `query` that allows you to access the parameters sent with a request.

```
app.get('/myroute/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query)); //log entire query object
   fs.writeFile('mynewfile3.txt', 'This is my text' + req.query.myvariable, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Replaced!');
        res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: "File written"
                });
   });
});
```